# Stop password characters from being shown

Tags: ios, security, privacy

When I type in a password in iOS 11.4.1, the last entered character is shown only for a split second.

For security reasons, I do not want the characters to get echoed. How do I disable this split second preview and show only the dots instead?

Answer (score 5):

Short answer, it is **not possible** to do so.

This functionality is built into iOS and it is by design. Showing a character for split second lets the user visually verify that correct character is entered.

If you are concerned about someone watching over your shoulder, consider using a password manager. Apple's iCloud keychain can store and enter passwords for you. If you upgrade to iOS 12, built-in support for 3rd party password managers in included in iOS. You get an option to enter password via it in the keyboard toolbar area. When entering password using password manager, no character is echoed and only dots are shown.

While it is also possible to use password manager in iOS 11.4.1, you'll have to resort to manually copying and pasting the password where the characters aren't echoed.

[Password Autofill in iOS 12 now works with 1Password, Dashlane, and LastPass](https://www.theverge.com/2018/9/17/17871408/apple-iphone-ios-12-password-autofill-1password-dashlane-lastpass)

Comment: Auto-filling login details by 3rd party managers works with Safari in iOS 11.x as well

Comment: Apple are retarded. I know that all my friends and I watch only he keyboard when entering passwords, how is a split-second preview in the password field useful to anyone except attackers

Comment: @theonlygusti Why Apple chose to do something or not is not something that can be commented on. If you have a concern, consider sharing [feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html) with Apple or better file it as a [bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/).